# testing send and receiving date in JMeter

Tags: java, json, date, jmeter

I have data in json file and I previous testing cerrectly sending and receiving this data in Postman. 
This data are in file json and this is a typical json file.
Now I transfer this test to JMeter. 
 Iny my Json file incluge data about event, in which customers can subscribe.
and I have one question, how can I do it, that data, which is send in postman (in json file) will be send in JMeter ?
and i can testing in JMeter correctly send and receive  this data?

Comment: There is no date in JSON. You need to provide details of what you need and tried

Comment: a small error.of course i think about data. Iny my Json file incluge data about event, in which customers can subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record the request you're executing in Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Expand "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording. You need to configure it to use JMeter as the proxy

   - Open`File -> Settings -> Proxy` screen
   - Tick both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols
   - Use `127.0.0.1` as the proxy host and `8888` as the proxy port

     [image]
3. Execute the request in Postman
4. That's it, JMeter should capture it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

---

A couple of hints:

1. If you need to **upload** the file make sure that the JSON file is present in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, otherwise JMeter will not be able to properly capture the request. Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more details
2. If you're sending JSON as request body and want to read the body from the file on your file system you can use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) in order to read the file and send it along with the request

   [image]

Comment: not exactly, bocuse I have a web socket connection, - web socket sampler by Peter.. so I think, that recording from postman is not necessery. I describe in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240841/jmeter-how-to-set-send-and-receiving-data-in-json-file-by-websocket

Comment: please help and explain, if read json by WebSocket Simple Write Sampler  is enough, or have to be by record from postman.

Comment: and how I can next process this data