# JMeter- how to set send and receiving data in JSON file - by WebSocket

Tags: jmeter

I have a back end application (only back end) which sends data to customers by WebSocket.
I testing this application using JMeter. In Jmeter I added plugin WebSocket Sampler by Peter..
Previously I am sending this data to customers by Postman. 
In my Json file incluge data about event, in which customers can subscribe. I have one question: How can I do it, that data, which is send in postman (in json file) will be send in JMeter?

Is it correctly way to read  my json file in Jmeter?
If not: Why not and how I can improve this?

2. How I can the best to process data - to variable from my json file?

Answer (score 0):

There is [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function, you can kill two birds with one with it, to wit:

1. Read a file from the file system
2. Store file contents into a JMeter Variable

For example the following expression:

```
${__FileToString(file.json,,myVar)}
```

will read `file.json` from JMeter's "bin" folder and store its contents into `${myVar}` JMeter Variable:

[image]

---

If you have multiple JSON files and want multiple JMeter threads to send different files - the easiest way is going for [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in attachmnent I show, what I set this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIPIj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbw7r.png)
what is wrong and how is the easiest way to improve this?
I'm not understand exactly, how I can add ${__FileToString(file.json,,myVar)} and variable myVar, 
and how exactly must be set FileToString and myVar in Thread group, as what of type test plan?
how improve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

OK I set this, and in View Result Three in **ERR** in Response Body is correctly return body json, so I dont know, why is **ERR* name
It is correctly? and if not, why is wrong and how I can improve this?